# String Switch Statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, incompatibility

I am developing a Java Class. Can I please have some help in using a Switch statement with a String data type.

Here is my code:

```
    String testString = "Nut";
    switch (testString)
    {
        case "Nut":
            if(NutCount < NutMaxCount) 
                NutCount += 1;
            break;
        case "Caramel":
            if(CaramelCount < CaramelMaxCount)
                CaramelCount += 1;
            break; 
        case "Chocolate":
            if(ChocolateCount < ChocolateMaxCount)
                ChocolateCount += 1;
            break;
        case "Marzipan":
            if(MarzipanCount < MarzipanMaxCount)
                MarzipanCount += 1;
            break;                        
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

incompatable types - found java.lang.String but expected int.

Comment: `String` can only be used in a `switch` statement under Java 7

Comment: Which raw produce this exception? Are you sure you are using Java7?

Comment: make sure your classpath targetting java7 not any older java sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will lead you to Java 7:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

You will require Java 7, so you can use `Strings` in a switch statement.

When you create a new project in your IDE (the ide in the picture is eclispse) make sure you select a Java that ends with 1.7

[image]

or

Just make each string correspond to a `int` value.

Answer (score 5):

Switch case with String only works with [**Java7**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Alternatively, you can use [**enum**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead for any version earlier than **`Java7`**

```
String testString = "Nut";
ValueEnum enumval = ValueEnum.fromString(testString);
switch (enumval) 
{
   case Nut:
            if(NutCount < NutMaxCount) 
                NutCount += 1;
            break;
   case Caramel:
            if(CaramelCount < CaramelMaxCount)
                CaramelCount += 1;
            break; 
   case Chocolate:
            if(ChocolateCount < ChocolateMaxCount)
                ChocolateCount += 1;
            break;
   case Marzipan:
            if(MarzipanCount < MarzipanMaxCount)
                MarzipanCount += 1;
            break;
}
```

Comment: There is no method "fromString()"?

Answer (score 1):

`String type isn't allowed to use as switch condition before JDK7`, 

so please use an `Integer variable` to instead of.